# save crystal report as a picture

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i want to save a Crystal report as a Picture using C# programming.if its not possible some how i want to save a report as a picture. can i do it???

Comment: you can "print" it as jpeg... independently of c#

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps..

step 1 download the [zen image printer](http://www.zan1011.com/jpg.htm)

step 2 [how to print cr w/o viewing it](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10110521/print-crystal-report-with.aspx) , [MSDN reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7dc0ccd6-1f57-496c-b320-f257bd343486/print-crystal-report-without-previewing-using-cnet?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

Comment: it says its printed. but i cannot find da picture

Comment: mmm.... may be you need to configure a default location inside zan image printer.... let me try to doit myself...